# HTML headings - absence of number in tag - bad pratice?

Tags: html

I have encountered an example of HTML5 that has an absence of a number in the heading tag unlike the normal `<h1>` to `<h6>` tags.

Is this an incorrect use of HTML? I believe that this use of the heading tag is incorrect, I did want to verify though.

```
 <article>
    <h>Subheading</h>
    This is some content
 </article>
```

Comment: Do you mean `<h1>Subheading</h1>` in your question?

Comment: @Siamak.A.M — Since it explicitly says "absence of a number", I doubt it.

Comment: @Quentin You are right. I voted up your answer but i think he forgot to type the number.

Comment: @Siamak.A.M: No, he didn't "forget". The fact that the number is missing is the whole point of the question. Didn't you read it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no `<h>` element in HTML. There was one proposed for XHTML 2, but that never took off.

Comment: Related section: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-h1,-h2,-h3,-h4,-h5,-and-h6-elements

Answer (score 0):

He can "create" new tags in HTML and then put as selector in CSS. But this is not a header though.